# How to make a dynamic reference to a table depending on a cell value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I've been making an Excel for myself, and I can't seem to get it right.

My Excel needs to do the following:
in the **"Main"** Sheet is my main **Named Table**; there, depending on the Input in the first four columns, certain data needs to be pulled out of another **Named Sheet - Named Table** with those same columns. I have achieved that by combining INDEX and MATCH (want to avoid the volatile INDIRECT).

The number of Sheets to pull the data from must be variable, but the structure (column names) of those is identical, so in the Table Reference the only thing that changes is the Table Name, like here:
**TAB_A**[minFz] or **TAB_B**[maxFz] (that would appear in the Formula bar if I was to do the selection manually). However, I need the Excel to search only in the named Table with a Name depending from a cell Content in the "Main" Sheet - the bolded part of the reference. The cell would be outside the Table Area but it is not a Problem to integrate it in the Main Table aswell. Excel 2007.

Images to help get the idea:
[Main Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWRwi.png)
[TAB_A Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sAGQ.png)
[TAB_B Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ0zf.png)

Appreciate all the help.
Thanks in forward.
Cheers,
Uros

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to use INDIRECT function?

Comment: What you are trying doesn't makes any sense, since all Tables has identical data in Col A to D,, Except Col M in Table A & B.  I would like to suggest use an array (CSE) formula, combination of INDEX & MATCH based on multiple criteria !!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid INDIRECT ? its purpose is for doing exactly what you want ?

Comment: I suppose avoiding `INDIRECT` because it recalculates whenever anything on the sheet is changed.

Comment: I recommend you explore using PowerQuery to first append the various lookup tables together and then use VLOOKUP to find data from the unioned table. You may have to install an AddIn to use PowerQuery in Excel 2007

Answer (score 0):

Well... it would seem like you want ONE item per cell in those columns on the Main sheet, and ALL the items to come from a single supporting sheet, not from a mix. Not that a mix would be harder (and I mean that literally:  not harder), but the title in K8 suggests you are not using the K column cells to vary the looked into Table.

The easiest way to approach it is actually not `INDIRECT()` and not from any horsepower standpoint. (After about 2003-2004 computers have been good enough to handle a HEAVY load in Excel and still perform nicely. Not some of the stupid loads you hear about, but raelly heavy loads. So `INDIRECT()` hasn't been such a problem for quite a while, and any computer you have that had Excel 2007 loaded on it is probably A-OK. Not gonna say it's OS is efficient anymore after 15 years of loading programs and abusing it, but still...)

The way forward is to use a simple `IF()`. Just test what the content of $K$9 is (note the dollar signs, or make it a Named Range) and let it choose the lookup formula appropriately.

(I'm not going to try to suss out just what your formula is, but will use a simple, representative pair of formulas. You can then substitute as appropriate.)

So, to select between TAB_**A**[minFz] and TAB_**B**[minFz], use an `IF()` like the following:

```
=IF($K$9="TAB_A",TAB_A[minFz],TAB_b[minFz])
```

You can nest the `IF()`'s, up to 7 **PER SET** and can use somewhat clever arrangements to ramp that up endlessly. For instance, set it up to have an `OR()` hold 2, 4, 8, 16... powers of two so you can "half-split" like on *The Price Is Right* and you can chain endless `IF()` nests together. Takes extra steps to unchain them, you can handle as many sheets as you need. And there are plenty of other techniques.

So you get the information DIRECTLY via the `IF()` and there is no performance hit with — o-o-o-o-h — volatile functions because once Excel calculates through them the first time, it knows it only needs to re-calc them if $K$9 changes. So only if that changes, and that'd be the case in ANY approach you used, rather than for any old change anywhere.

And in any case, you have to understand and accept that if you want something **dynamic** you have to accept re-calc-ing when the key elements to the dynamic aspect change.

A note about the lookup formulas you need to fit in as the outputs of the various possibilities in the `IF()` testing:  they will be identical except for the sheet reference in them. So write one, make it work, then copy it in and change the sheet reference each place you paste it as an outcome in your formula. Just one letter to change, looks like, so easy-peasey. Don't rewrite them from scratch each time you need an outcome!